# ORA-01688: unable to extend table (...) The journal Entry Cannot Be Saved

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I need help, I get error

> ORA-01688: unable to extend table (...) The journal Entry Cannot Be
>   Saved

when running create accounting in OPM Financial.

I need to know the cause of the error and how to solve it.
I was searching in Oracle support website but i cant open the cause (description) because I don't have account in Oracle support.

Please help, what the cause of error and how to fix it.

Many thanks,
Makhali

Answer (score 3):

This is what Oracle says:

> ORA-01688: unable to extend table string.string partition string by
>   string in tablespace string
>
> Cause: Failed to allocate an extent of the required number of blocks
>   for table segment in the tablespace indicated.
>
> Action: Use ALTER TABLESPACE ADD DATAFILE statement to add one or more
>   files to the tablespace indicated

If you are a DBA, do it yourself. If you're not, ask them to do it for you.